# Using Arguments to maven profile

Tags: maven, maven-2, maven-3, aem, maven-profiles

Is there anyway i can pass the argument in the maven profile. Like i want to run the server on specific port if specified otherwise to the default profile.
Like when i run mvn clean install -Pdeploy 4322 than the package should deploy to server running on the port 4322 otherwise to 4052.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, you can pass environment variables, like this : `mvn ... -Pdeploy -DdeploymentPort=4322`

Then access the variable in the profile like this:

```
...
<port>${deploymentPort}</port>
...
```

Comment: Just to add on.. This will be a child of your properties node.

Answer (score 2):

You can define default properties to use in your parent pom.xml

```
 <properties>
    <crx.userId>admin</crx.userId>
    <crx.password>admin</crx.password>
    <crx.host>localhost</crx.host>
    <crx.port>4502</crx.port>
</properties>
```

Then later in the parent pom.xml or in a pom.xml of a child project you can use these properties.

Example:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.day.jcr.vault</groupId>
    <artifactId>content-package-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <extensions>true</extensions>

    <configuration>
        <targetURL>http://${crx.host}:${crx.port}/crx/packmgr/service.jsp</targetURL>
        <userId>${crx.userId}</userId>
        <password>${crx.password}</password>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Then in your maven command use the `-D[property name] = [value]` to overwrite the default value.